# ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'db'

Tags: mysql, database, privileges, access-denied, mysql-error-1044

I want to begin writing queries in MySQL.

`show grants` shows:

```
+--------------------------------------+
| Grants for @localhost                |
+--------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ''@'localhost' |
+--------------------------------------+
```

I do not have any user-id but when I want to make a user I don't have privilleges, also I don't know how to make privileges when even I don't have one user!

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'parsa'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'parsa';
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER pr
ivilege(s) for this operation
```

I tried to sign in as root:

```
mysql> mysql -u root -p;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql
 -u root -p' at line 1
mysql> mysql -u root -p root;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql
 -u root -p root' at line 1
```

Comment: You need to log in as a user with permissions. At least `root` should have been created when you installed MySQL.

Comment: during installation it tells me to set password and i set it to root now what can I do?

Comment: You need to log in as root—e.g., by running `mysql -u root -p`. Then you'll have full permissions on the database server, and you can create other users.

Comment: when you log in using command line, do the following to log in as root: mysql -u root -p

Comment: I edited I tried it in the past maybe my syntax is not correct I dunno

Comment: @nikparsa: No, you'd run that instead of 'mysql'—from the shell prompt, not at the mysql prompt.

Comment: @derpbert what should i do now exactly?

Comment: @nikparsa: If you're on Windows, I think there is a different start menu entry (should have 'root' in its name, I believe). Or run it from the `cmd` prompt. On Unix/Linux, type `mysql -u root -p` in a terminal (at the bash prompt). On Mac OS X, pull up a Terminal.app and also type `mysql -u root -p`.

Comment: I tried root with quotation too I am in windows xp I hate xp! linux is so better!

Comment: This is because you haven't login to MySQL using root user. Try login using "mysql -u root".

Comment: Heads up: If you attempt to use a database with an incorrectly typed name, it will throw this error. Make sure that you've entered your database name correctly.

Comment: you have to type `exit;` to go back to bash before you can start mysql as the root user: `mysql -u root -p`

Answer (score 239, accepted):

No, you should run `mysql -u root -p` in bash, not at the MySQL command-line.
If you are in mysql, you can exit by typing **exit**.

Comment: how can I go to bash?I had problem installing mysql see here http://superuser.com/questions/377679/mysql-client-not-working-windows-xp I just know abt it in command line

Comment: use 'quit' to exit the mysql,then you will be in bash

Comment: FYI by default the password is blank

Comment: What if I am using windows?

Comment: exit or quit is not working for me, please provide another way. I'm on windows 10

Comment: @PHPFan and posterity, Even for windows, its same. From, command prompt enter `mysql -u root -p`

Comment: If `exit` won't work, you're probably still in the process of typing an instruction so mysql is interpreting `exit` as part of that instruction and not the `exit` keyword (should be seeing `->` when you hit enter if this is the case). Try typing a semicolon and hit enter to terminate the instruction; then the next line (that should start with `mysql>` and NOT `->` and it will respond appropriately to the `exit` keyword.

Comment: You can also try `ctrl+d` to leave MySQL.

Answer (score 55):

You may need to set up a root account for your MySQL database:

In the terminal type:

```
mysqladmin -u root password 'root password goes here'
```

And then to invoke the MySQL client:

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```

Comment: This one worked for me, it was working fine initially and then suddenly stopped working one day. Any idea, why this happens in the first place?

Comment: @soleshoe  i m getting error : sudo: mysqladmin: command not found    please help me what can i do??   mysql is alreay running in System Preference.

Comment: I get:

mysqladmin: Can't turn off logging; error: 'Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation'

Answer (score 32):

I was brought here by a different problem.
Whenever I tried to login, i got that message because instead of authenticating correctly I logged in as anonymous user. The solution to my problem was:

To see which user you are, and whose permissions you have:

```
select user(), current_user();
```

To delete the pesky anonymous user:

```
drop user ''@'localhost';
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me even though I was using "mysql -u username -p". Very strange: user() was my username, but current_user() was localhost... dont know why?

Comment: @Leftteris hi ..  i m getting this error : Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation    When i try to drop user ''@'localhost';

Comment: +-----------------+----------------+
| user()          | current_user() |
+-----------------+----------------+
| fantomx1@localhost | @localhost     |
+-----------------+----------------+ |
thx, I got this, when the anonymous user existing, I could login with whatever existing user without password even when they had password but their password didnt work, but they didnt have privileges, or even with any non existing thinked out string user 'sdasdsa',  but the current user was always anonymous, after dropping him it started to work

Comment: this site has info on how to drop the anonymous user.
http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.1/en/default-privileges.html

Answer (score 29):

This is something to do with user permissions. Giving proper grants will solve this issue.

Step [1]: Open terminal and run this command

```
$ mysql -uroot -p
```

Output [1]:
This should give you mysql prompt shown below

[image]

Step [2]:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'parsa'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password';
mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to 'parsa'@'localhost';
```

Syntax:

```
mysql> grant all privileges on `database_name`.`table_name` to 'user_name'@'hostname';
```

> Note:
>
> - hostname can be IP address, localhost, 127.0.0.1
> - In `database_name`/`table_name`, * means all databases
> - In `hostname`, to specify all hosts use '%'

Step [3]: Get out of current mysql prompt by either entering `quit` / `exit` command or press `Ctrl+D`.

Step [4]: Login to your new user

```
$ mysql -uparsa -pyour_password
```

Step [5]: Create the database

```
mysql> create database `database_name`;
```

Comment: when I do `CREATE USER 'parsa'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password';` there get error: ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: Have you logged into mysql client using root user

Comment: This solved my issue: `grant all privileges on *.* to 'parsa'@'%';` . I'm using docker-compose, is there a way I can pass this command after build?

Comment: I encountered the same problem when I migrated my existing database from phpmyadmin xampp to mysql. This finally worked for my node.js mysql app

Comment: This is the best answer on this topic!

Answer (score 11):

You might want to try the full login command:

```
mysql -h host -u root -p
```

where host would be `127.0.0.1`.

Do this just to make sure cooperation exists.

Using `mysql -u root -p` allows me to do a a lot of database searching, but refuses any database creation due to a path setting.

Answer (score 8):

connect mysql with sudo & gives permission for the necessary user using,

```
sudo mysql -u user;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

Comment: this fixed mine

Comment: but i use this *.* to grant access to all database/tables

Answer (score 7):

First, if you are unfamiliar with the command line, try using phpmyadmin from your webbrowser. This will make sure you actually have a mysql database created and a username.

This is how you connect from the command line (bash):

```
mysql -h hostname -u username -p database_name
```

For example:

```
fabio@crunchbang ~ $ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u fabio -p fabiodb
```

Comment: `-p` is for password and you are using it to pass database name. Also, for password, there **shouldn't** be a space b/w `-p` and the actual password. Use `-D` to connect to a specific database.

Answer (score 7):

If you are in a `MySQL` shell, exit it by typing **exit**, which will return you to the command prompt.

Now start `MySQL` by using exactly the following command:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

If your username is something other than root, replace 'root' in the above command with your username:

```
sudo mysql -u <your-user-name> -p
```

It will then ask you the `MySQL` account/password, and your `MySQL` won't show any access privilege issue then on.

Comment: after enter password i getting "sudo: mysql: command not found" Please help me out on this

Comment: it shouldn't be "sudo:", it should be "sudo" ... If it is not a typo, I think this is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

@Nickparsa … you have 2 issues:

1). `mysql -uroot -p` 
should be typed in bash (also known as your terminal) not in MySQL command-line. You fix this error by typing

```
exit
```

in  your MySQL command-line. Now you are back in your bash/terminal command-line.

2). You have a syntax error:

```
mysql -uroot -p;
```

the semicolon in front of -p needs to go. The correct syntax is:

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

type the correct syntax in your bash commandline. Enter a password if you have one set up; else just hit the enter button. You should get a response that is similar to this:
[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi i got the abow screen direcly after  fire this commend.  /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql      but after that when i try to create database using " CREATE DATABASE books; " i am getting error :  ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'books'  please help me

Answer (score 2):

Just as a side note, if you just followed all grant privilege instruction and you are not seeing the effect, restart your sql workbench or any sql client you are using. You can also restart your server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using roles to confer least privilege on my database application users. I kept getting 'ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user...' until I RTFM and discovered I had to give each user a default role(s) in order their account could be authenticated when they logged in.

```
#create a role
CREATE ROLE 'rolename';

#give necessary privileges to role
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT ON database.table TO 'rolename';

#create user
CREATE USER 'username'@'host' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

#give the user a role(s)
GRANT 'rolename' TO 'username'@'host';

#set the user's default otherwise it's ERROR 1044
SET DEFAULT ROLE 'rolename' FOR 'username'@'host';
```

Answer (score 0):

**Most Developers** log-in to server(I assume you r having user-name and password for mysql database) then from Bash they switch to `mysql> prompt` then use the command below(which doesn’t work

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```

*What needs to be done is use the above command in the bash prompt--> on doing so it will ask for password if given it will take directly to mysql prompt and*

**then database, table can be created one by one**

I faced similar deadlock so sharing the experience

Answer (score 0):

I had the command correct per above answers, what I missed on was on the Workbench, where we mention 'Limit Connectivity from Host' for the user, it defaults to "%" - change this to "localhost" and it connects fine thereafter!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'john'@'localhost' to database 'apple'

When I tried to select `apple` database by login with the user `john` as shown below:

```
use apple
```

So, I gave all privileges on all the tables in `apple` database (`apple.*`) to the user `john` with [GRANT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) by login with the user `root` as shown below, then I could solve the error:

```sql
GRANT ALL ON apple.* TO 'john'@'localhost';
```

Or:

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON apple.* TO 'john'@'localhost';
```

Comment: How does this substantially differ [from your answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77349302)?