# cannot connect to Msql data base

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

i cannot seem to create a connection to Mysql database from the following code. Can you please let me know if there is anything missing from this code. Since i have not used php code much i  might have missed out something.

on submitting code im getting the following error
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Host '31.170.160.80' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in /home/a5847996/public_html/check_db.php on line 15

### here is the code im using

```
<body>
    <?php
     $server   = "-";
     $database = "-";
     $username = "-";
     $password = "**************";

     $mysqlConnection = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
      if (!$mysqlConnection)
      {
       echo "Please try later.";
      }
      else
      {
       mysql_select_db($database, $mysqlConnection);
      }
   ?>
    </body>
```

Comment: the mysql server is configured to only be accessable from the server itself

Comment: The error basically tells you exactly what is wrong. Your webserver is not allowed to connect to the database server. You should contact your hoster.

Comment: ...and double check mysql server name so you're connecting to the correct server/host name.

Comment: you should use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead of the `mysql_*` extensions, they're deprecated.

Comment: what is `check_db.php on line 15`

Answer (score 2):

**Go to your MySQL Prompt and issue this command.**

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:

mysql> use mysql

mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'31.170.160.80' IDENTIFIED BY 'your-root-password'; 

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

**Don't forget to assign your parameters !**

Comment: im not sure if i understand the purpose of this code. might need a little explanantion.

Comment: you are just "granting the privileges to your host". Try it and let us know.

Comment: im getting "access denied" message when i try this

Comment: SQL query:

USE mysql

MySQL said: 

#1044 - Access denied for user 'a5847996_admin'@'localhost' to database 'mysql'

Comment: You need to execute the first statement in the terminal and the last 3 at mysql prompts. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838777/error-1044-42000-access-denied-for-user-localhost-to-database-db