# Running mysql from terminal

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a database in terminal but I get the error

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mydatabase'
```

All I've done so far is install `mysql` and install the workbench to go along with it.

This is my personal computer so I have administrator privilege from this log-in account.

Another thing is that the database I created in the workbench doesn't show up when I type the command

```
SHOW DATABASE;
```

in the terminal.

Comment: Have you set a root password?  If not, [read these docs first](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/default-privileges.html) to set one, after which you may grant privs for other users. Specify those other users on the command line `mysql -u username -p'password'`

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838777/error-1044-42000-access-denied-for-user-localhost-to-database-db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to login. Try:

`mysql -u root -p`

You will be asked for a password.

More information: `mysql --help`

Hope that helps. :-)