# Ruby on rails - Mysql2::Error Access denied for user 'simple_cms'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working through a RoR tutorial from [lynda.com](http://Lynda.com)
for a week already & without changing anything today i was not able to see my content on localhost due to this error :

```
Mysql2::Error Access denied for user 'simple_cms'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I do know that this problem has been referred many times befored , i am still not able to find a confirmed solution .

To give you further information regarding my set up my working enviroment is `Yosemite 10.10.4` - `Rails 3.2.22` - `5.6.22 MySQL` - `WEBrick 1.3.1`

i have set up the SQL database as it looks below on the `database.yml` file on the config folder of the project

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: simple_cms_development
  pool: 5
  username: simple_cms
  password: **********
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock


test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: simple_cms_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: simple_cms_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Also i noticed that by trying to connect via terminal on the database with the password

> `§ mysql -u root -p`

and again i get the error ::`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`.

I tried to restart manually MySQL server from menu & all i got was the same error!

What is the problem and it doesn't let me log in with the settings as i did all this time ?

Is it a problem with rails or with mysql settings?

While everything seems to be as it has to be,do i have to change something on the `database.yml` file?

Comment: On what port are you running your database?

Comment: Oh, and try `mysql -uroot -p` without the space between u and root

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, my database runs on `3306` port & after i runned this command `mysql -uroot -p` i got the same error message as i stated above!

Comment: What does `mysql -uroot -P3306 -p` say? Does mysql ask for a Password?

Comment: Perhaps you did not Need a Password? try `mysql -uroot -P3306`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this problem by uninstalling the current MySQL via terminal with the command `brew uninstall MySQL` & then reinstalling it with `brew`, from the beginning!

After the installation, when i tried to login into MySQL i did it through the command :`mysql -u root -p`! At this point on the password request i added the one that has been set up before on the config file :`database.yml` and it logged in succesfully!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have a very similar issue as well when configuring and setting up my app -- also called simple_cms too. :) After you did 'brew install mysql' to reinstall it, did you do anything else or just go with 'mysql -u rails_user -p simple_cms_development then enter the same password you have in database.yml? Because I still get the same password error here.

Answer (score 0):

The error-message

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).
```

will Show up if you entered a wrong password. Reset your Password according to [this link.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply , i just found out that when i run the command `show databases;` the response does not contain the database `simple_cms_development`.How is this possible to happen by the time i was working on this about a week already?

Comment: you can easily check if the databse actually exists: In the filesystem go to your mysql/data Folder. Here a Folder for each database is created. Do you see a Folder named `simple_cms_development`?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not referred there anywhere .. What should i do now ? I am even more confused..

Comment: when you can run `Show databases` and see a result you can connect to your database. Where you run this comand, run a `create database simple_cms_development`.

Comment: `mysql> create database simple_cms_development;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'simple_cms_development'`

This is the result of this command , does this mean that it actually exists?

Comment: you are not connected to your database. Reset your Password as described in the link above or in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838777/error-1044-42000-access-denied-for-user-localhost-to-database-db

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 3 things :

1. Check if Mysql Server is On(or Started)
2. Change the password logging in mysql from terminal.
3. Create a database in your project folder using:

   $ rake db:create

and that should do it for you so it did for me.