# xampp Creating Databases Error 1044 (42000)

Tags: mysql, xampp

I tried to create a database using MySQL. I encountered this problem. How can I fix it?

> ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database
>   'sample_db'

Comment: this might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838777/error-1044-42000-access-denied-for-user-localhost-to-database-db

Answer (score 0):

You should check user privileges, there are users take privileges on specific database only, and others are super users who take all privileges and through this users you can create database.
You can see that through phpMyAdmin application and can access it by:
Http:\localhost\phpMyAdmin