# Xampp access denied error

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am facing this error every time I create a database in CLI interface of mysql:

[image: Image of error]

I am using Xampp

Comment: You have to grant privilege to database user to perform action on that database

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set up a root account for your MySQL database:

In the terminal type:

```
mysqladmin -u root password 'root password goes here'
```

And then to invoke the MySQL client:

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```

more reference [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838777/error-1044-42000-access-denied-for-user-localhost-to-database-db)

Answer (score 1):

A simple and 100% working solution for this problem is:
Install Xampp outside the C: Folder and it will definitely work for you, without any permission problems ever.
But remember to provide xampp-control.exe administrative privileges always to terminate any port problems.

Comment: a perfect and esay solution

Comment: @Avinashjain Thanks buddy.

Comment: Outside of the C: folder? What do you mean? I have XAMPP in its own folder: xampp (though directly under C:\). So you're saying to install the xampp folder into something like C:\Users\Me? I tried that once and got different permissions issues, strangely. Where do you install it? I'm not comfortable running XAMPP with admin privileges because I don't know exactly what it could ever do using those privileges... see what I mean? It's a security concern. Most other apps I use don't require that.