# How do I set xampp?

Tags: xampp

I am getting this error while setting up xampp.
Error says "Could not drop existing database
SQL: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'dvwa'."

I got the error while trying to create a database. I have tried editing the config file too. Whats happening?

Answer (score 0):

it's a problem with the permission to the user `local` : you have to go with the user `root`.
this post could help you : [ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'db'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838777/error-1044-42000-access-denied-for-user-localhost-to-database-db)